# Zabbix integration with AWS and or Azure

Tags: amazon-web-services, zabbix, amazon-cloudwatch, grafana, azure-monitor

I am trying to figure out direct integration between Zabbix and AWS CloudWatch or Azure Monitor. I have seen YT videos available to integrate Zabbix with grafana first and then integrate grafana with AWS or Azure monitoring solution. But I am just wondering

1. if we have any direct integration available to AWS cloudwatch (for example) using which I can populate the default metrics of AWS services (EC2, Redis, Cache and others).?
2. and also monitor the metrics like script execution or any other DB related metrics from RDS instance (for example).

Any guidance would really be appreciated.